# Dropping view in bigquery fails thru UI and api

Tags: google-bigquery

Dropping any existing views on sandbox_views dataset of bq project test-altar-543 fails with "Not Found: Dataset test-altar-543:sandbox" errpr. Currently there are 7 views and they are referencing the tables in sandbox dataset. All fail to drop!

Any new view creation with the same content succeeds and also dropping it later works too.

https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=207&thanks=207&ts=1420492761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is accepted as a bug by google, please see the link on the question for the work around!

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but notice the link you posted got an answer, so for the sake of completion I will rephrase what they said here:

The error seemed to have to do with the fact that the views referenced deleted tables, which caused a 404 unfound when trying to delete the view (because the view was targetting a now non-existant table).

The solution they suggested was to update the views into not looking at the deleting tables (so possibly doing a simple "select 'test'" or something like that, as a view) would let you deleting them.

To update a view, you simply have to "resave" it. The new view will take the place of the old one.

Comment: That link is for google and in the meantime, I've posted here for the community and we know it is accepted as bug by google on that link.

Comment: oh I know. I just added the workaround Google posted here in case the link ever goes dead :)